# Extract a FAT .a file Mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, extract, data-extraction

I have a FAT .a archive on my Mac (a library) and I just wanted to know how I could extract the files from it?

Comment: Do you want to write a program to do this, or are you looking for one that is already made?

Comment: looking for one that is already made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lipo input_file -extract architecture -output output_file`

This is for extracting a single architecture of a Universal Binary archive.   Not sure if this helps, though.